# Add Views on layout with timer - Android

Tags: java, android, timer

I have a function to add buttons to my activity layout:

```
void addLeftButton() {
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    int height = 200;
    int width = 300;
    btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));
    btn.setTag(10);
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    layout.addView(btn);
}
```

I call this function with a timer like this:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            addLeftButton();
        }
    },0,10);
```

For some reasons the app launches and stops immediately. If I call my button function once from `onCreate` then I adds the button as expect.

Any ideas why calling it with a timer doesn't work?

Comment: Read the error message in LogCat. My guess is you can't modify the UI from a non-UI thread.

Comment: What kind of an exception/log do you get when the application stops? Where are you creating Timer, is it possible you create it before the layout is inflated, making findViewById return null?

Comment: @merterpam - I create the timer "onCreate" method.

Answer (score 0):

I think nbokmans is right, the problem should be because you try to modify UI-elements from a non-UI thread. Instead of Timer, you can use `runOnUiThread`:

```
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Button btn = new Button(StartActivity.this);
            int height = 200;
            int width = 300;
            btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));
            btn.setTag(10);
            ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.deneme);
            layout.addView(btn);
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 10);
        }
    });
```